# Overlayed bar chart in chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I am using chartJS chart with type bar and trying to create overlaping bar.
It must be 3 bars for one date, overlaping each other.

idea:

- the bar with the biggest value shoud have (z-index: 0), and it will be the height of this column
- bars with lower value should have bigger z-index, so we can see it.

there is a prop order, but it works for all sets of bars, so some bar can fully overlaped another bars.

Is it possible using chartJS? or should i use another library?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with highchart. There are many variations you can try out

Here is one such example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'A basic column chart',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['USA', 'China', 'Brazil', 'EU', 'India', 'Russia'],
        crosshair: true,
        accessibility: {
            description: 'Countries'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '1000 metric tons (MT)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' (1000 MT)'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            stacking: "overlap"
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Corn',
            data: [406292, 260000, 55000, 68300, 27500, 14500]
        },
        {
            name: 'Wheat',
            data: [51086, 136000, 107000, 141000, 107180, 77000]
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

You can explore lot of option in the API guide and adjust as per your needs
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global

Hope that helps.